# rich text area ->php mailer ->email not formatting text, instead it is showing html tags

Tags: php, html, forms, email, richtextbox

I'm creating a php mailer form for my company website, on the form I have a rich text area, when data is input into the box and the form submitted, the data gets sent in the email showing the html tags, it does not format the text. I assume what it is doing is correct but how do I make the mailer format the text before the email is sent?

an example of my code (the rest of the mailer works, this is the most important part):

```
$otherinformation= htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['otherinformation']);

if(!empty($otherinformation)) {
$htmlmessage .= "
<td valign='top' class='tntTextContent' style='padding: 9px 18px; line-height:150%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;color: #494540;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 15px;text-align: justify;'>
<div style='text-align: justify;'>$otherinformation</div>
</td>
";}
```

If I type any text into the text box it will come out such as this in the final email:

```
hello<div><br></div><div style="text-align: right;">hello</div>
```

I would like it to be formatted and not show the tags. Thanks

Comment: You need to post the code where you're sending the email. Most likely you're not including the proper headers.

Comment: $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers  .= "From: $from\r\n";

These are the headers I'm currently using.

Comment: Okay, then whatever you're using to view isn't rendering the email in html format. Do other html emails load properly for you? Also, since we can't see the rest of the code, we have no idea if it is a fomatting issue etc.

Comment: Thanks, I've managed to sort it, it seems the Rich Text Converter that I was using didn't convert the text correctly, I just installed another and that now works.